# R is there a way to find Inf/-Inf values?

Tags: r, random-forest, na

I'm trying to run a randomForest on a large-ish data set (5000x300).  Unfortunately I'm getting an error message as follows:

```
> RF <- randomForest(prePrior1, postPrior1[,6]
+                    ,,do.trace=TRUE,importance=TRUE,ntree=100,,forest=TRUE)
Error in randomForest.default(prePrior1, postPrior1[, 6], , do.trace = TRUE,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

So I try to find any NA's using :

```
> df2 <- prePrior1[is.na(prePrior1)]
> df2 
character(0)
> df2 <- postPrior1[is.na(postPrior1[,6])]
> df2 
numeric(0)
```

which leads me to believe that it's Inf's that are the problem as there don't seem to be any NA's.

Any suggestions for how to root out Inf's?

Comment: It doesn't have to be `Inf`. It could also be `NaN`, as the errors says. Regardless, `?Inf` answers your question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're probably looking for `is.finite`, though I'm not 100% certain that the problem is Infs in your input data.

Be sure to read the help for `is.finite` carefully about which combinations of missing, infinite, etc. it picks out. Specifically, this:

```
> is.finite(c(1,NA,-Inf,NaN))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> is.infinite(c(1,NA,-Inf,NaN))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

One of these things is not like the others. Not surprisingly, there's an `is.nan` function as well.

Comment: In general, the warnings about NA/NaN/Inf from randomForest are **not** caused by NA/NaN/Inf, but in fact by character data.

Answer (score 12):

randomForest's *'NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call'* is often a **false warning**, and really irritating:

- you will get this if any of the variables passed is character
- actual NaNs and Infs **almost never happen in clean data**

My fast-and-dirty trick to narrow things down, do a binary-search on your variable list, and use token parameters like `ntree=2` to get an instant pass/fail on the subset of variables:

```
RF <- randomForest(prePrior1[m:n],ntree=2,...)
```

Answer (score 5):

In analogy to `is.na`, you can use `is.infinite` to find occurrences of infinites.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `with`, e.g.:

```
> with(df, df == Inf)
        foo   bar   baz   abc ...
[1,]  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE ...
[2,]  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

joran's answer is what you want and informative. For more details about `is.na()` and `is.infinite()`, you should check out https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/is.na-methods.html 
and besides, after you get the logical vector which says whether each element of the original vector is NA/Inf, you can use the `which()` function to get the indices, just like this:

```
> v1 <- c(1, Inf, 2, NaN, Inf, 3, NaN, Inf)
> is.infinite(v1)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> which(is.infinite(v1))
[1] 2 5 8
> is.na(v1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> which(is.na(v1))
[1] 4 7
```

the document for `which()` is here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/any.html